# Angular get height of EmbeddedViewRef

Tags: angular

```
ItemData {
   isShowHeader: boolean;
   isShowFooter: boolean;
   contentText: string;
   isShowTime: boolean;
   timeText: string;
   isShowName: boolean;
   name: string;
}
<div *customFor="let item of itemList">
  <div *ngIf="isShowHeader">xxx</div>
  <div *ngIf="isShowName">{{ name }}</div>
  <div>{{ contentText }}</div>
  <div *ngIf="isShowTime">{{ timeText }}</div>
  <div *ngIf="isShowFooter">xxxx</div> 
<div>
```

I have some kind of above sample template and data object list. customFor directive will create the
template dynamically.

```
const viewRef = viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(templateRef, { $implicit: item }, index);
viewRef.detectChanges();
const height = viewRef.rootNodes[0].offsetHeight;
```

Above code can get the correct height of the item data.

But when i change some flags of the item data (for example: change isShowHeader: true -> false, etc), I don't want to recreate embeddedView.

```
const viewRef = viewContainerRef.get(index) as EmbeddedViewRef<any>;
viewRef.context.$implicit=item;
viewRef.detectChanges(); 
const height = viewRef.rootNodes[0].offsetHeight;
```

The height is changed a bit, but still not correct. Is there anything I need to do to get the correct height for the bind item data after calling detectChanges?

What's the createEmbeddedViewRef did and can get the height of view after calling detectChanges()?
For reusing view, detectChanges() cannot reflect the height immediately?

I expect to get the correct height of the layout when the bind item data changes.

I try with
viewContainerRef.detach(index);
viewContainerRef.insert(viewRef, index);

Still not work.